# How to split the string key and values using preg match

Tags: php, string, split, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to know how to split the below strings as array key values using preg_match or any other methods, I was facing the problem while reading the email content

```
$string = " username: demo password: 123456789"
```

I want to like this

```
[username]=demo
[password]=12346890
```

Comment: a string split on space won't work?

Comment: here is a very useful link for this type of thing: http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3

Answer (score 3):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) instead:

```
if (preg_match_all('/(\w+):\s+(\w+)/', $string, $matches)) {
    $result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/233849)

It matches a bunch of word-like things, followed by a colon and space, then followed by another bunch of word-like things.

[**Expression details**](https://regex101.com/r/fI9vE0/1)

Comment: The above code display as only one record as follows Array
(
    [Username] => demo
); I want to  password fields also

Comment: @sv.sasi This seems like the correct/best answer.  If you ever return to SO, please award this answer the green tick so that your question is deemed resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the explode method if you wanted as well.

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

So you could do...

```
$string = " username: demo password: 123456789";
$string = trim($string);   //Trim the string for first space like jack said
$stringsplit = explode(" ", $string);

echo $stringsplit[0] . " = " . $stringsplit[1];
echo $stringsplit[2] . " = " . $stringsplit[3];

//then build it to the way you want
//If you need it exactly the way you have it listed above it would be something like..

$stringsplit[0] = str_replace(":", "", $stringsplit[0]);    //these 2 lines only to get
$stringsplit[2] = echo str_replace(":", "", $stringsplit[2]);    //rid of the :

echo "[" . $stringsplit[0] . "]=" . $stringsplit[1];
echo "[" . $stringsplit[2] . "]=" . $stringsplit[3];
```

Comment: The string is value is unpredictable but I can't use explode method so my choice is preg_match for example the string values as follows "Re: my test imap sv sasi kumar on Fri, 12 Dec 2014 14:25:59 +0530


username:test
password:123456789"

Comment: yea makes sense to use a preg_match_all then i didn't catch that in your post lol no worries